# XRC error : " 18: too many children in grid sizer: 10 > 2 x 2 (consider omitting the number of rows or columns)"

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

When I build my project have some error , I have no idea how to fix, please help me.

error message:

18:10:42: XRC error: 18: too many children in grid sizer: 10 > 2 x 2 (consider omitting the number of rows or columns)
18:10:42: XRC error: 18: unexpected item in sizer

Tools:
Python2.7 - wxPython

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MEPG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message.
Count the number of rows and columns you are adding to your grid sizer and adjust the declared number of row/columns accordingly. Currently you are adding either too many rows or too many columns.
The other way around this, is to declare rows or columns as 0 (zero). The grid sizer will then calculate the number it requires itself.